# Escalabilidade com Pm2 ou Docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, escalabilidade

Boa tarde, estou com uma duvida sobre as diferenças..

Tenho uma arquitetura 
Back
Nodejs, Redis

Frontend
VueJs

Qual a diferença entre colocar para escalar com docker swarm e colocar PM2..

Valew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes

Pm2 é um Gerenciador de processos para node, basicamente ele te ajuda a monitorar a aplicação e conseguir aumentar a disponibilidade.

Docker - ferramenta para isolar os processos, independente do tipo de linguagem.

Docker swarm - É o cara responsável por administra o docker em vários nós diferentes

O Pm2 está limitado apenas ao contesto do nodejs, enquanto o docker oferecer uma solução independente de linguagem, ele isola os recursos da maquina e usa o conceito de conteiner onde o processo de build, deploy e recovery são muito mais tranquilos.

Agora comparando ao docker swarm, ele consegue pegar as replicar e replicar em vários hosts, e fica administrando eles o Pm2 não faz isso com o nodejs

podemos dizer que o docker seria uma camada mais abaixo da sua aplicação.